# Add/update events on my calendar using ASP.NET C# in a webforms app

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to be able to add/update events on my Google Calendar using ASP.NET C#.  I've researched plenty, but am going in circles.  I need clarification and direction on what type of authentication is needed, etc.

My webforms app will be used by multiple people.  Each person has been granted access to the target calendar.  I want the app to make a call to add (and update) events from that app.

My understanding is that I don't need the user's permission to add events to my own calendar that I'm sharing with them.  Accurate?

Do I need oAuth, API key or other authentication?  Where is clear walk-through code in addition to clarification on credentials needed?

Answer (score 0):

It was stated in the Google Calendar API documentation that:

> Every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must
>   include an authorization token. The token also identifies your
>   application to Google.

Also using the method [`Events: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#auth). Same with the [`Events: update`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update). Just make sure you need to add the following scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`).

Check the example code snippet of [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) and [`update`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#examples) method.